# Angular 9 - ERROR in In Ivy, decorator metadata must be inline

Tags: decorator, ivy, angular9

Angular 9 and ivy have only recently been published. But the migration is giving me a headache right now. Unfortunately the listed error is nowhere to be found and is not very meaningful.
I ask for help!

[compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhMH1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem and it was fixed by replacing

```
@Injectable(({ providedIn: 'root' }))
```

with

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
```

Main idea is that decorator should accept object !

Comment: Thank you very much, in fact it was just that. However, the error message could be a bit more detailed.